# take snapshot with c# (AForge)

Tags: c#, image, webcam, aforge

I did this Code with AForge. The Output should be a Picture taken with the Wabcam(Saved in "C:\users\me\Desktop\Picture.jpg").
The Code just dont do that and I have no Idea why. Thanks

```
    static void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\users\me\desktop\picture.jpg");
       }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection( FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString );
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( video_NewFrame );
        videoSource.Start();
        videoSource.SignalToStop();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static  bool x = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice); VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            if (x == true)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    static void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Skydr\Desktop\C++_Project\a.jpg");
        x = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is calling the 'SignalToStop' when it's not done receiving the frame. The code lets the camera receive the picture then shutdown the videosource without being interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Adola i solved the Problem like this :

```
     static void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\users\me\desktop\picture.jpg");



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool finish = false ;
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection( FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );
         VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString );
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( video_NewFrame );
        videoSource.Start();
        do{
        if (File.Exists(@"c:\users\me\desktop\picture.jpg"))
        {
            finish = true;
        videoSource.SignalToStop();
       }
        } while (finish != true);
    }
```